# How to convert a path containing .. traversals to a canonical path, in PHP?

Tags: php, string

```
  //CONVERT INPUT TO OUTPUT:
  // input => /var/www/../html/../a/data/
  // output => /var/a/data/
```

Is there a better solution to creating the real path to the location than this?

```
$string = "/var/www/../html/../a/data/";

$str = explode('/', $string);
if ($str[0] == "")
    array_shift($str);

$max = sizeof($str);
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++){
    $str[$i] = "/" . $str[$i];
    if (strpos($str[$i], "..")){
        unset($str[$i]);
        unset($str[$i-1]);
    }
}

echo $string = implode($str);
```

Comment: What is the pattern behind this to get to this output?

Comment: Uh, @Barmar ... no?  There's no code to review here.

Comment: @nhgrif He posted the code in an answer.

Comment: @Barmar Answer's aren't part of the question.  His *answer* might be appropriate for [codereview.se], but his *question* definitely isn't, and his question definitely isn't a question about improving code.

Comment: @nhgrif He clearly intends his answer to be part of the question. It begins with the question "Is there a better solution than this?". He just doesn't understand the protocol here.

Comment: @Barmar And he equally wouldn't understand the protocol at [codereview.se].  Don't recommend bad questions to other sites.  Just close them for whatever appropriate close reason.  Is this question Too Broad?  Is it Unclear?  Choose one of those close reasons and don't recommend people ask bad questions on other sites and force other sites to *also* have to deal with a poor question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming core PHP functions are permitted, how about this?

```
<?php
echo realpath('/var/www/../html/../a/data/');
```

Comment: wow! I feel quite dumb right now! Thank you.

Comment: Ha, no worries @Artur. Of course, yours may have been fine if they were looking for an algorithm.